# what is the difference between mid and substring in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i just saw both the MID() and SUBSTRING() function returns the same result. i want to know what is the difference between both?. Is both the function usage is same with different alias?

```
SELECT MID('mysample',2,3);

SELECT SUBSTRING('mysample',2,3);
```

returns  : `ysa`

Comment: MID(str,pos,len) is a synonym for SUBSTRING(str,pos,len).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [`MySQL documentation`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_mid) says:

> `MID(str,pos,len)` is a synonym for `SUBSTRING(str,pos,len)`.

The documentation also says that [`MID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_mid) requires 3 arguments while [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) is more flexible. The `len` argument is optional. When it is not present, the function returns the substring starting with `pos` until the end of the string.

```
SUBSTRING(str, pos, len)
SUBSTRING(str, pos)
```

`SUBSTRING()` also allows a more verbose syntax (inherited from the standard SQL):

```
SUBSTRING(str FROM pos FOR len)
SUBSTRING(str FROM pos)
```

**Update:**

Some tests I just ran on several different MySQL installations (different versions) reveal that on the current versions of MySQL, `MID()` is just a synonym of `SUBSTRING()` and it also accepts all the syntax variations of `SUBSTRING()`.

Comment: Also SUBSTR is synonym for SUBSTRING in MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

MID() is a synonym for SUBSTRING() in MySQL.

Comment: so there is no difference

Comment: Not true, MID is only a synonum for Substring(str, pos, len)

Comment: basic difference lies, how they indice the string characters...thats it